# After upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04.1 LTS, uname reports wrong kernel

Tags: kernel

I have been struggling with this for few hours and I am not able to find a solution to this problem. Normally I would not care if uname reports a wrong kernel, but when installing Virtualbox, this is a showstopper.
Output of  `cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image:`

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic        3.13.0-32.57                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic         4.4.0-59.80                          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic  3.13.0-32.57                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic   4.4.0-59.80                          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-virtual            4.4.0.59.62                          amd64        Transitional package.
ii  linux-image-generic                  4.4.0.59.62                          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image


And finally the spurious uname output:

Linux bluemountain 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any ideas why this disparity occurs and a posible solution?

Comment: No idea, but have you tried removing the 3.13 packages? It might be enough to wake up the system.

Comment: Use  a live cd to do get your data safe

Comment: Is it a VPS????

Answer (score 1):

On the command line run the following to ensure you have the latest updates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and probably best to update the initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and check you have the latest kernel installed, check in /boot:

```
ls /boot
```

and update the boot loader script to ensure it has been updated:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that all works OK then reboot and see if that works.